# Показатель громкости в bass.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, bass.dll, bass.net

Как в `Label` отобразить текущий процент громкости (40%) или показатель громкости(40/100)? Ниже код самого компонента и код компонента в классе.

```
private void xvolume_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            BassLike.SetVolumeToStream(BassLike.Stream, xvolume.Value);
        }

public static void SetVolumeToStream(int stream, int vol)
        {
            Volume = vol;
            Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, Volume / 100F);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, сделать событие изменения значения громкости и при вызове события записывать данное значение в Label.Text.